# OS specified group in Gemfile

Tags: ruby, bundler

I installed a gem `pry-windows` that is obviously used only in windows.

Is there way to make a group by OS in `Gemfile` like this?

```
group :windows do
  gem 'pry-windows'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /win32/ 
  gem 'pry-windows'
end
```